# Strip email and text from a full tag

Tags: python

How I can correctly get out email and text between *< a href.. > < / a >* tag ?

My code:

```
import re
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = input("Enter url -")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
count = 0
tags = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("mailto"))
for tag in tags:
    count += 1
    print(tag)
print("Total amount of mails:", count)
```

My programm is receiving a full tag `<a href="mailto:johntest@test.com">John Test</a>` and I want to get only email adress and name. How can I correctly strip it out ?

Comment: You should be able to use a regex for that. Experiment a little with something like https://regexr.com/ and post a new question if you can't solve it. Python supports regexes with the `re` module.

Comment: Have you checked the BeautifulSoup docs?

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a href="mailto:johntest@test.com">John Test</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser="html.parser", features="lxml")

for element in soup.find_all("a"):

    if "mailto" in element["href"]:
        email = element["href"].split(":")[1]
        name = element.text

        print(email, name)
```

Output

```
johntest@test.com John Test
```